# Making an ordering system and I keep getting errors

Tags: python, tkinter

I Keep getting this error:
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'TOTAL: 0'

It's for the third line, but I wanted to include the whole section just in case.

```
order_total = orderTotalLabel.cget("text").replace("TOTAL : ", "")
order_total = order_total.replace("$","")
updated_total = int(order_total) + prices[displayLabel.cget("text")]
orderTotalLabel.configure(text="TOTAL : " + str(updated_total) + "$")
```

I don't know how to fix this? I will also add the prices just in case it is something from there causing the issue?

```
prices = {
    "Chocolate Ice Cream" : 3,
    "Vanilla Ice Cream" : 3,
    "Swirl Ice Cream" : 4,
    "Butterscotch Ice Cream" : 4,
    "Cheesecake Ice Cream" : 4,
    "Moosetrack Ice Cream" : 5,
}
```

I am just trying to make a simple ordering system and when I add to cart, it is throwing this error.

```html
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import*
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import random
from datetime import date
from datetime import datetime

prices = {
    "Chocolate Ice Cream" : 3,
    "Vanilla Ice Cream" : 3,
    "Swirl Ice Cream" : 4,
    "Butterscotch Ice Cream" : 4,
    "Cheesecake Ice Cream" : 4,
    "Moosetrack Ice Cream" : 5,
}


root = Tk()

root.title("TTC-Ice Cream Shop")

#------------FUNCTIONS----------#

# Random Order ID
def ORDER_ID():
    numbers = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
    letters = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O',
               'P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z']
    order_id = "ICS_"
    random_letters = ""
    random_digits = ""
    for i in range(0,3):
        random_letters += random.choice(letters)
        random_digits += str(random.choice(numbers))

    order_id += random_letters + random_digits
    return order_id


#Region Add to Order Button
def add():
    #Updating transaction label
    current_order = orderTransaction.cget("text")
    added_dish = displayLabel.cget("text") + "...." + str(prices[displayLabel.cget("text")]) + "$ "
    updated_order = current_order + added_dish
    orderTransaction.configure(text=updated_order)

    #Updating Order Total Label
    order_total = orderTotalLabel.cget("text").replace("TOTAL : ", "")
    order_total = order_total.replace("$","")
    updated_total = int(order_total) + prices[displayLabel.cget("text")]
    orderTotalLabel.configure(text="TOTAL : " + str(updated_total) + "$")

    #Region Remove Button Function
def remove():
    dish_to_remove = displayLabel.cget("text") + "...." + str(prices[displayLabel.cget("text")])
    transaction_list = orderTransaction.cget("text").split("$ ")
    transaction_list.pop(len(transaction_list) - 1)

    if dish_to_remove in transaction_list:
        #update transaction label
        transaction_list.remove(dish_to_remove)
        updated_order = ""
        for item in transaction_list:
            updated_order += item + "$ "

        orderTransaction.configure(text=updated_order)

        #update transaction total
        order_total = orderTotalLabel.cget("text").replace("TOTAL : ", "")
        order_total = order_total.replace("$", "")
        updated_total = int(order_total) - prices[displayLabel.cget("text")]
        orderTotalLabel.configure(text="TOTAL : " + str(updated_total) + "$")

#Display Button Functions
def displayChocolate():
    ChocolateDishFrame.configure(
        relief="sunken",
        style="SelectedDish.TFrame"
    )
    VanillaDishFrame.configure(style="DishFrame.TFrame")
    SwirlDishFrame.configure(style="DishFrame.TFrame")
    CheesecakeDishFrame.configure(style="DishFrame.TFrame")
    MoosetrackDishFrame.configure(style="DishFrame.TFrame")
    displayLabel.configure(
        image=ChocolateImage,
        text="Chocolate Ice Cream",
        font=('Helvetica', 14, "bold"),
        foreground="white",
        compound="bottom",
        padding=(5,5,5,5),
    )

def displayVanilla():
    VanillaDishFrame.configure(
        relief="sunken",
        style="SelectedDish.TFrame"
    )
    ChocolateDishFrame.configure(style="DishFrame.TFrame")
    SwirlDishFrame.configure(style="DishFrame.TFrame")
    CheesecakeDishFrame.configure(style="DishFrame.TFrame")
    MoosetrackDishFrame.configure(style="DishFrame.TFrame")
    displayLabel.configure(
        image=VanillaImage,
        text="Vanilla Ice Cream",
        font=('Helvetica', 14, "bold"),
        foreground="white",
        compound="bottom",
        padding=(5,5,5,5),
    )

def displaySwirl():
    SwirlDishFrame.configure(
        relief="sunken",
        style="SelectedDish.TFrame"
    )
    ChocolateDishFrame.configure(style="DishFrame.TFrame")
    VanillaDishFrame.configure(style="DishFrame.TFrame")
    CheesecakeDishFrame.configure(style="DishFrame.TFrame")
    MoosetrackDishFrame.configure(style="DishFrame.TFrame")
    displayLabel.configure(
        image=SwirlImage,
        text="Swirl Ice Cream",
        font=('Helvetica', 14, "bold"),
        foreground="white",
        compound="bottom",
        padding=(5,5,5,5),
    )

def displayButterscotch():
    ButterscotchDishFrame.configure(
        relief="sunken",
        style="SelectedDish.TFrame"
    )
    ChocolateDishFrame.configure(style="DishFrame.TFrame")
    VanillaDishFrame.configure(style="DishFrame.TFrame")
    SwirlDishFrame.configure(style="DishFrame.TFrame")
    CheesecakeDishFrame.configure(style="DishFrame.TFrame")
    MoosetrackDishFrame.configure(style="DishFrame.TFrame")

    displayLabel.configure(
        image=ButterscotchImage,
        text="Butterscotch Ice Cream",
        font=('Helvetica', 14, "bold"),
        foreground="white",
        compound="bottom",
        padding=(5,5,5,5),
    )

def displayCheesecake():
    CheesecakeDishFrame.configure(
        relief="sunken",
        style="SelectedDish.TFrame"
    )
    ChocolateDishFrame.configure(style="DishFrame.TFrame")
    VanillaDishFrame.configure(style="DishFrame.TFrame")
    SwirlDishFrame.configure(style="DishFrame.TFrame")
    MoosetrackDishFrame.configure(style="DishFrame.TFrame")
    displayLabel.configure(
        image=CheesecakeImage,
        text="Cheesecake Ice Cream",
        font=('Helvetica', 14, "bold"),
        foreground="white",
        compound="bottom",
        padding=(5,5,5,5),
    )

def displayMoosetrack():
    MoosetrackDishFrame.configure(
        relief="sunken",
        style="SelectedDish.TFrame"
    )
    ChocolateDishFrame.configure(style="DishFrame.TFrame")
    VanillaDishFrame.configure(style="DishFrame.TFrame")
    SwirlDishFrame.configure(style="DishFrame.TFrame")
    CheesecakeDishFrame.configure(style="DishFrame.TFrame")
    displayLabel.configure(
        image=MoosetrackImage,
        text="Moosetrack Ice Cream",
        font=('Helvetica', 14, "bold"),
        foreground="white",
        compound="bottom",
        padding=(5,5,5,5),
    )

#Region Generates Reciepts from Order Button
def order():
    new_receipt = orderIDLabel.cget("text")
    new_receipt = new_receipt.replace("ORDER_ID :", "")
    transaction_list = orderTransaction.cget("text").split("$ ")
    transaction_list.pop(len(transaction_list) -1)

    order_day = data.today()
    order_time = data.now()

    for item in transaction_list:
        item += "$ "

    with open(new_receipt, 'w') as file:
        file.write("Ice Cream Shop")
        file.write("\n")
        file.write("----------------------------")
        file.write("\n")
        file.write(order_day.strftime("%x"))
        file.write("\n")
        file.write(order.time.strftime("%x"))
        file.write("\n\n")
        for item in transaction_list:
            file.write(item + "\n")
        file.write("\n\n")
        file.write(orderTotalLabel.cget("text"))

    orderTotalLabel.configure(text ="TOTAL : $0")
    orderIDLabel.configure(text = "ORDER ID: " + ORDER_ID())
    orderTransaction.configure(text = "")

#endregion


#---------- STYLING AND IMAGES ----------#
#region style configurations

s=ttk.Style()
s.configure('MainFrame.TFrame', background= "#F8F8FF")
s.configure('MenuFrame.TFrame', background= "#F8F8FF")
s.configure('DisplayFrame.TFrame', background="#9AC0CD")
s.configure('OrderFrame.Tfram',background="#B7C4CF")
s.configure('DishFrame.TFrame', background="#F8F8FF", relief="raised")
s.configure('SelectedDish.TFrame', background="#C4DFAA")
s.configure('MenuLabel.TLabel',
           background="#9AC0CD",
           font=("Arial", 13, "italic"),
           foreground="white",
           padding=(5,5,5,5),
           width=21
           )

s.configure('orderTotalLabel.TLabel',
           background="#9AC0CD",
           font=("Arial", 10, "bold"),
           foreground="white",
           padding=(2,2,2,2),
           anchor="W"
           )

s.configure('orderTransaction.TLabel',
           background="#F8F8FF",
           font=("Helvetica", 12),
           foreground="white",
           wraplength=170,
           padding=(3,3,3,3),
           anchor="NW"
           )


#end region

#region Images
#Top Banner Images

LogoImageObject = Image.open("menu/logo.jpg").resize((200, 200))
LogoImage=ImageTk.PhotoImage(LogoImageObject)

TopBannerImageObject=Image.open("menu/banner.jpg").resize((800, 200))
TopBannerImage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(TopBannerImageObject)


#Menu Images
displayDefaultImageObject=Image.open(r'C:\Users\joco1\PycharmProjects\pythonProject11\menu\love.jpg').resize((350, 360))
displayDefaultImageObject=ImageTk.PhotoImage(displayDefaultImageObject)

ChocolateImageObject=Image.open(r'C:\Users\joco1\PycharmProjects\pythonProject11\menu\Chocolate.jpg').resize((350, 334))
ChocolateImage=ImageTk.PhotoImage(ChocolateImageObject)

VanillaImageObject=Image.open(r'C:\Users\joco1\PycharmProjects\pythonProject11\menu\Vanilla.jpg').resize((350, 334))
VanillaImage=ImageTk.PhotoImage(VanillaImageObject)

SwirlImageObject=Image.open(r'C:\Users\joco1\PycharmProjects\pythonProject11\menu\Swirl.png').resize((350, 334))
SwirlImage=ImageTk.PhotoImage(SwirlImageObject)

ButterscotchImageObject=Image.open(r'C:\Users\joco1\PycharmProjects\pythonProject11\menu\Butterscotch.jpg').resize((350, 334))
ButterscotchImage=ImageTk.PhotoImage(ButterscotchImageObject)

CheesecakeImageObject=Image.open(r'C:\Users\joco1\PycharmProjects\pythonProject11\menu\Cheesecake.jpg').resize((350, 334))
CheesecakeImage=ImageTk.PhotoImage(CheesecakeImageObject)

MoosetrackImageObject=Image.open(r'C:\Users\joco1\PycharmProjects\pythonProject11\menu\Moosetrack.jpg').resize((350, 334))
MoosetrackImage=ImageTk.PhotoImage(MoosetrackImageObject)

#endregion

#------------- WIDGETS ---------------#

#region Frames
# Section Frames

mainFrame=ttk.Frame(root, width=800, height=580, style='MainFrame.TFrame')
mainFrame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="NSEW")

topBannerFrame= ttk.Frame(mainFrame)
topBannerFrame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="NSEW", columnspan=3)

menuFrame=ttk.Frame(mainFrame, style='MenuFrame.TFrame')
menuFrame.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=3, pady=3, sticky="NSEW")

displayFrame = ttk.Frame(mainFrame, style="Displayframe.TFrame")
displayFrame.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=3, pady=3, sticky="NSEW")

orderFrame = ttk.Frame(mainFrame, style ="OrderFrame.TFrame")
orderFrame.grid(row=1, column =2, padx=3, pady=3, sticky="NSEW")

#Dish Frames
ChocolateDishFrame=ttk.Frame(menuFrame, style = "DishFrame.TFrame")
ChocolateDishFrame.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="NSEW")

VanillaDishFrame=ttk.Frame(menuFrame, style="DishFrame.TFrame")
VanillaDishFrame.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky="NSEW")

SwirlDishFrame=ttk.Frame(menuFrame, style="DishFrame.TFrame")
SwirlDishFrame.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky="NSEW")

ButterscotchDishFrame=ttk.Frame(menuFrame, style="DishFrame.TFrame")
ButterscotchDishFrame.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky="NSEW")

CheesecakeDishFrame=ttk.Frame(menuFrame, style="DishFrame.TFrame")
CheesecakeDishFrame.grid(row=5, column=0, sticky="NSEW")

MoosetrackDishFrame=ttk.Frame(menuFrame, style="DishFrame.TFrame")
MoosetrackDishFrame.grid(row=6, column=0, sticky="NSEW")


#endregion

#Top Banner Images

LogoLabel= tk.Label(topBannerFrame, image=LogoImage, background= "#9AC0CD")
LogoLabel.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="W")

RestaurantBannerLabel= ttk.Label(topBannerFrame, image=TopBannerImage, background ="#9AC0CD")
RestaurantBannerLabel.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="NSEW")

#endregion

#region Menu Section
MainMenuLabel=ttk.Label(menuFrame, text="MENU", style="MenuLabel.TLabel")
MainMenuLabel.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="WE")
MainMenuLabel.configure(
    anchor="center",
    font=("Helvetica", 14, "bold")
)

ChocolateDishLabel=ttk.Label(ChocolateDishFrame, text="Chocolate -- $3", style="MenuLabel.TLabel")
ChocolateDishLabel.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="W")

VanillaDishLabel=ttk.Label(VanillaDishFrame, text="Vanilla -- $3", style="MenuLabel.TLabel")
VanillaDishLabel.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="W")

SwirlDishLabel=ttk.Label(SwirlDishFrame, text="Swirl Scoop -- $4", style="MenuLabel.TLabel")
SwirlDishLabel.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="W")

ButterscotchDishLabel=ttk.Label(ButterscotchDishFrame, text="Butterscotch -- $4", style="MenuLabel.TLabel")
ButterscotchDishLabel.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="W")

CheesecakeDishLabel=ttk.Label(CheesecakeDishFrame, text="Cheesecake -- $4", style="MenuLabel.TLabel")
CheesecakeDishLabel.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="W")

MoosetrackDishLabel=ttk.Label(MoosetrackDishFrame, text="Moosetrack -- $5", style="MenuLabel.TLabel")
MoosetrackDishLabel.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="W")


ChocolateDisplayButton=ttk.Button(ChocolateDishFrame, text="Display", command=displayChocolate)
ChocolateDisplayButton.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10)

VanillaDisplayButton=ttk.Button(VanillaDishFrame, text="Display", command=displayVanilla)
VanillaDisplayButton.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10)

SwirlDisplayButton=ttk.Button(SwirlDishFrame, text="Display", command=displaySwirl)
SwirlDisplayButton.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10)

ButterscotchDisplayButton=ttk.Button(ButterscotchDishFrame, text="Display", command=displayButterscotch)
ButterscotchDisplayButton.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10)

CheesecakeDisplayButton=ttk.Button(CheesecakeDishFrame, text="Display", command=displayCheesecake)
CheesecakeDisplayButton.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10)

MoosetrackDisplayButton=ttk.Button(MoosetrackDishFrame, text="Display", command=displayMoosetrack)
MoosetrackDisplayButton.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10)

#endreigon

#Order Section

orderTitleLabel=ttk.Label(orderFrame, text="ORDER")
orderTitleLabel.configure(
    foreground="white", background="#9AC0CD",
    font=("Helvetica", 14, "bold"), anchor="center",
    padding=(5,5,5,5),
)
orderTitleLabel.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="EW")

orderIDLabel=ttk.Label(orderFrame, text="ORDER NUMBER : " + ORDER_ID())
orderIDLabel.configure(
    background="#9AC0CD",
    foreground="white",
    font=("Helvetica", 11, "italic"),
    anchor="center",
)
orderIDLabel.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="EW", pady=1)


#Region Display Section
displayLabel=ttk.Label(displayFrame, image=displayDefaultImageObject)
displayLabel.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="NSEW", columnspan=2)
displayLabel.configure(background="#9AC0CD")

addOrderButton = ttk.Button(displayFrame, text="ADD TO CART", command = add)
addOrderButton.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=2, sticky="NSEW")

removeOrderButton=ttk.Button(displayFrame, text="REMOVE")
removeOrderButton.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=2, sticky="NSEW")

orderTransaction = ttk.Label(orderFrame, style='orderTransaction.TLabel')
orderTransaction.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky="NSEW")

orderTotalLabel = ttk.Label(orderFrame, text="TOTAL: $0", style="orderTotalLabel.TLabel")
orderTotalLabel.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky="EW")

orderButton=ttk.Button(orderFrame, text="ORDER")
orderButton.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky="EW")



#endregion


#---------------GRID CONFIGURATIONS ----------------#

mainFrame.columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
mainFrame.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
menuFrame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
menuFrame.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
menuFrame.rowconfigure(2, weight=1)
menuFrame.rowconfigure(3, weight=1)
menuFrame.rowconfigure(4, weight=1)
menuFrame.rowconfigure(5, weight=1)
menuFrame.rowconfigure(6, weight=1)
orderFrame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
orderFrame.rowconfigure(2, weight=1)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It's telling you that 'TOTAL: 0' is not a valid integer. The first step to debug this is to examine `order_total` after the first line of code that you posted to see if it's what you think it is, and then again after the second line.

Comment: Yes, that's my issue is I can not figure out what I am missing. I'm kind of new to Python so I was hoping someone would be able to see what I am not?
The full code for adding to the order is this, I'm not sure if that helps..its above the order_total

def add():
    #Updating transaction label
    current_order = orderTransaction.cget("text")
    added_dish = displayLabel.cget("text") + "...." + str(prices[displayLabel.cget("text")]) + "$ "
    updated_order = current_order + added_dish
    orderTransaction.configure(text=updated_order)

Comment: Did you what I suggested? When debugging, one of the first things to do is verify that variables have the values that you assume they have.

Comment: No, because I don't think I understand what you're asking me to do honestly. The only variables are the ones in my price list

Comment: `order_total` is a variable.

Comment: Hi Megan! Welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: Would you be able to add the rest of your code to the question? The code you've included calls functions you've not shown us, so it's hard to know what they do ‍

Comment: Thank you that does help me understand better. Sorry, I am very new to Python. However, I am still not seeing how it isn't working correctly bc it should be 0. I edited and added the whole code. I hope that helps

Comment: Simply put, print out the result of `order_total = orderTotalLabel.cget("text").replace("TOTAL : ", "")`. You're probably assuming it's something like `$123.45` but it's not. You need to verify that very first statement is doing what you think it should be doing before worrying about the next line of code.

Comment: You've added too much code. The [mcve] should be as minimal as possible while still reproducing the error. Also, please remove the use of images unless the image is necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Use f-string format.    On line 52 and 53 change to updated_total = f"order_total    {prices['Chocolate Ice Cream']}"
    orderTotalLabel.configure(text=f"TOTAL :   {str(updated_total)} $")

Comment: The error tells you that the string you want to convert to integer is `"TOTAL: 0"`.  However your code wants to replace `"TOTAL : "` (note that a space after `"TOTAL"` by `""` in the string which will do nothing.

Comment: ace1668 OMG that was it! THANK YOU GUYS SO MUCH! :D

Comment: OK I have one more question. Why Won't it remove items from my order? :( It is not throwing any errors, but when I click remove it does nothing. I did update the font in the order box to black because I thought it was the order box as a whole not working, but it is displaying the added items.